# Least Possible Value as described by Modulo Condition MATLAB

Tags: matlab, modulo, modulus

I am about to create a function in matlab which will accept multiple modulo and their corresponding remainders then it will determine the least possible value that will fit the given modulo conditions. Major trouble is that I am not allowed to use mod() and rem() built-in function in matlab. Can you help me with this?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you have been asked to implement the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: @Maurits Yes it's Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @Oli not definitely as homework, I encountered such problem while I was searching for mod() and rem() functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create custom `my_mod` and `my_rem` functions without using `mod` and `rem`, and you can use these as you would use `mod` and `rem`.

```
function modulus = my_mod(X, Y)
if isequal(Y, 0)
    modulus = X;
elseif isequal(X, Y)
    modulus = 0;
elseif (isequal(abs(X), Inf) || isequal(abs(Y), Inf))
    modulus = NaN;
else
    modulus = X - floor(X./Y) .* Y;
end
return

function remainder = my_rem(X, Y)
if isequal(Y, 0)
    remainder = NaN;
elseif isequal(X, Y)
    remainder = 0;
elseif (isequal(abs(X), Inf) || isequal(abs(Y), Inf))
    remainder = NaN;
else
    remainder = X - fix(X./Y) .* Y;
end
return
```