# Modulo and remainder (Chinese remainder theorem) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, modulo, chinese-remainder-theorem

How do I find the least possible value in Matlab, given the modulo values and its remainder values in an array? for example:

```
A=[ 23 90 56 36] %# the modulo values
B=[  1  3 37 21] %# the remainder values
```

which leads to the answer `93`; which is the least possible value.

---

#### EDIT:

Here is my code but it only seems to display the last value of the remainder array as the least value:

```
z = input('z=');
r = input('r=');
c = 0;
m = max(z);
[x, y] = find(z == m);
r = r(y);
f = find(z);
q = max(f);
p = z(1:q);
n = m * c + r;
if (mod(n, p) == r)
    c = c + 1;
end
fprintf('The lowest value is %0.f\n', n)
```

Comment: See the "chinese remainder theorem".

Comment: There are already several CRT implementations in the MATLAB File Exchange, for instance: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32649-chinese-remainder-theorem-for-integers-simple) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5851)...

Comment: @EitanT can you please help me in making this program? i really suck at programming and we are only allowed to use rem and mod commands and i'm not gaining any progress

Comment: @Jey [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544240/least-possible-value-as-described-by-modulo-condition-matlab) seems to be identical to yours. Also, it would be best if you'd have something done (embed that code into the original question) so that it can be improved into a working program.

Comment: @EitanT: If you realize a question is a duplicate, please consider casting a close vote.

Comment: @Jonas i'm sorry i thought it's not a duplicate because the other question does not allow rem and mod while mine only allows rem and mod commands

Comment: @Jonas I've reached my daily limit already :) @ Jey, if you're still stuck, please update this question and paste your code into it. It would be easier to help you when you've got something going already...

Comment: @EitanT okay i'll update it later! but i'm kinda ashamed of my program because its really bad because of my poor MATLAB skills

Comment: @Jey Don't be! You cannot get better if you don't try.

Comment: z=input('z=');   
r=input('r=');  
c=0;  
m=max(z);  
[x,y]=find(z==m);  
r=r(y);  
f=find(z);  
q=max(f);  
p=z(1:q);  
n=m*c+r;  
if (mod(n,p)==r)  
c=c+1;  
end  
fprintf('The lowest value is %0.f\n',n)  
  
Here is my code but it only seems to display the last value of the remainder array as the least value
@EitanT

Comment: End a line with two spaces to add a <br/> linebreak doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Jey <br/> tags don't work in comments because formatting in comments is somewhat limited. I've pasted your code into your original question itself.

Comment: @EitanT thanks! but if you input the values in the first question it only produces 21 as the least value which is the last number in the B array

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so your goal is to find the smallest `x` that satisfies `B(i) = mod(x, A(i))` for each `i`.

[This page](http://www.math.okstate.edu/~wrightd/crypt/lecnotes/node21.html) contains a very simple (yet thorough) explanation of how to solve your set of equations using the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). So, here's an implementation of the described method in MATLAB:

```
A = [23, 90];                                  %# Moduli
B = [1, 3];                                    %# Remainders

%# Find the smallest x that satisfies B(i) = mod(x, A(i)) for each i
AA = meshgrid(A);
assert(~sum(sum(gcd(AA, AA') - diag(A) > 1)))  %# Check that moduli are coprime
M = prod(AA' - diag(A - 1));
[G, U, V] = gcd(A, M);
x = mod(sum(B .* M .* V), prod(A))

x =
    93
```

You should note that this algorithm works only for moduli (the values of `A`) which are [coprime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers)!

In your example, they are not, so *this will not work for your example* (I've put an `assert` command to break the script if the moduli are not coprime). You should try to implement yourself the [full solution for non-comprime moduli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_successive_substitution)!

P.S
Also note that the [`gcd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcd.html) command uses [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). If you are required to implement it yourself, [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38112-chinese-remainder-theorem/content/invmodn.m) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13949-euclids-algorithm) might serve you as good references.